# Smallest and largest values of a vector length

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

```
|u| = 2 and |v| = 3, what are the largest and smallest values for |u−v| Give
a geometric explanation of your results.
```

So I used the triangle inequality definition to find the smallest and largest values for |u-v| however I'm unsure (and don't fully understand the concept) how to explain what these values mean geometrically..

so I adapted the triangle inequality for |u-v| to:

|u| - |-v| <= |u - v| <= |u| + |-v|

And by this I got the values:

smallest: 2-3 = -1

largest: 2+3 = 5

But how do I explain this geometrically?

Comment: Vector length cannot be negative. Your first inequality is true but not sufficiently precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, the smallest value can't be -1 because we're talking about |u-v|, which is the vector's magnitude, a quantity which is always positive. Have you learned about vector addition as a "tip-to-tail" composition? That's how I suggest thinking of this. What it would mean is that |u+v| is maximal when the vectors are in the same direction and minimal when they're in opposite directions. (|u+v|={u-(-v)|, and since |v|=|-v|=3 we can just as well look at it as a problem about |u+v|.) If you take three steps forward and then two more, you've taken five steps. If you take three forward and two back, you're one step away from the start. The triangle inequality does the same thing - just don't forget that you're still talking about magnitude.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the geometric reasoning. I know that |-v| = |v| and like you said it can just be viewed as the same as |u+v| which was how I got my values, but the triangle inequality:  |x|-|y|<=|x+y|<=|x|+|y| expressed the lower as |u| - |v| which was how I got -1, am I just supposed to express this as |v| - |u| instead since it cannot be negative?

Comment: Sorry i guess what i'm asking is, can u and v be interchanged in this instance and be expressed as: |v| - |u| <= |u - v| ?

Comment: You're welcome! The lower bound should actually be ||v|-|u||; see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality. Sorry for the slow response; I've been unconscious.